# Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'data' does not exist in type 'PromiseLike<T>'

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a method  that makes a request to a server and, based on the URL, it might return completely differently shaped data.

Before this I was just casting the expected interface into the returned object:

```
    const data = Promise.resolve(makeSignedRequest(requestParameters));
    return data as Promise<AwesomeResponse>;
```

but today I came across this syntax, where I can tell the method explicitly what kind of data I'm expecting:

```
    const data = Promise.resolve(makeSignedRequest<AwesomeResponse>(requestParameters));
    return data;
```

Now. the makeSignedRequest may return types like, `AwesomeResponse`, `GreatResponse`, `AmazingResponse` but there is a common thing in all these. They all share the same structure - the structure of `BaseResponse`.

All my responses extend the `BaseResponse`, so we're cool there.

Having said all that, TypeScript is still complaining about the following code:

```ts
import https from "https";
export interface BaseResponse {
    meta: {};
    data: Array<{}>;
    error?: {
        statusCode: number | undefined;
        statusMessage: string | undefined;
    };
}

export const makeSignedRequest = <T>(url): Promise<T> => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // create Request with event listeners
        const req = https.request(url, (res) => {
            res.on("end", () => {
                if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
                    resolve({
                        data: [],
                        meta: {},
                        error: {}
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
};
```

the `resolve({data: [],` gets heavily underlined by VS Code, because as I mentioned in the title,

```
Argument of type '{ data: never[]; meta: {}; error: { statusCode: number | undefined; statusMessage: string | undefined; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T | PromiseLike<T> | undefined'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'data' does not exist in type 'PromiseLike<T>'.
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Could you cut this down to a [mre]?

Comment: I've updated the code sample that still produces the same typescript error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints):

```
export const makeSignedRequest = < T extends BaseResponse  > ...
```

and a type assertion:

```
      resolve({
        data: [],
        meta: {},
        error: {
          statusCode: res.statusCode,
          statusMessage: res.statusMessage,
        },
      } as T);
```

This code works for me in VSCode with TS 3.8.3

```
export interface BaseResponse {
    data: [];
    meta: {};
    error?: {
        statusCode: number | undefined;
        statusMessage: string | undefined;
    };
}

function makeSignedRequest<T extends BaseResponse>(): Promise<T> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // create Request with event listener
        resolve({
            data: [],
            meta: {},
            error: {},
        } as T);
    });
}
```

Comment: nope. that throws a whole set of new errors. first I'd need to convert the expression to 'unknown' first. eg (as unknown as T) and then `Argument of type 'T' is not assignable to parameter of type '(T extends BaseResponse ? any : any) | PromiseLike<T extends BaseResponse ? any : any> | undefined'.
  Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'PromiseLike<T extends BaseResponse ? any : any>'.`

Comment: What TS version do you use?

Comment: TypeScript 3.8.3

Comment: Why do you have `T extends BaseResponse ? any : any`? Should be just `T extends BaseResponse`.

Comment: T extends BaseResponse ? any : any ???? I don't have that. that's the error message from vscode if I do what you suggested.

Comment: I don't get such errors. I've updated my answer. Maybe your builtin TS version differs from your compiler.

Comment: You're right! well, kinda: ```resolve(({...} as unknown) as T);``` Thanks!

Comment: It's not a cast, it's an *assertion*, including it means the compiler isn't checking the actual value.

Answer (score 0):

You are saying that: your function return a generic type Promise, so `resolve` only accepts T as parameter. But `{data: [], meta: {}, error: {}}` is not T, as T can be anything (string, number ...), so it won't compile. Your function does not make sense with generic type, it should return `Promise<BaseReponse>`, that's all. Return `Promise<T>` does not produce any benefit